# string parsing & date formatting unix

Tags: bash, datetime, unix

I am looking for unix command to parse the below strings to the desired format as below.

> Connected to Integration Service: [is_infa01]. Integration Service
>   status: [Running] Integration Service startup time: [Mon May 09
>   10:27:22 2016] Integration Service current time: [Sun Jun 05 21:57:33
>   2016] Folder: [TEST] Workflow: [wf_MASTER_DAILY] version [2]. Workflow
>   run status: [Succeeded] Workflow run error code: [0] Workflow run
>   error message: [Completed successfully.] Workflow run id [425197].
>   Start time: [Sat Jun 04 13:14:11 2016] End time: [Sat Jun 04 13:20:37
>   2016] Workflow log file:
>   [/informatica/pc961/server/infa_shared/Working/infa01/WorkflowLogs/wf_MASTER_DAILY.log]

I am looking to parse the above string and get the below output (with date format as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:DD)

```
Workflow run status|Start time|End time
Succeeded|2016-06-04 13:14:11|2016-06-04 13:20:37
```

I can get the value of individual values like below

```
grep "Workflow run status:" | cut -d'[' -f2 | cut -d']' -f1
grep "Start time:" | cut -d'[' -f2 | cut -d']' -f1
grep "End time:" | cut -d'[' -f2 | cut -d']' -f1
```

but how to make the desired output with date formatting?

Comment: It would help if you format the input properly. It's unclear where the line starts & where it ends. Do not format logs using block-quote. Use `pre` for formatting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming GNU grep, you can wrap it all up like this:

```
string="Connected to Integration Service: [is_infa01]. Integration Service status: [Running] Integration Service startup time: [Mon May 09 10:27:22 2016] Integration Service current time: [Sun Jun 05 21:57:33 2016] Folder: [TEST] Workflow: [wf_MASTER_DAILY] version [2]. Workflow run status: [Succeeded] Workflow run error code: [0] Workflow run error message: [Completed successfully.] Workflow run id [425197]. Start time: [Sat Jun 04 13:14:11 2016] End time: [Sat Jun 04 13:20:37 2016] Workflow log file: [/informatica/pc961/server/infa_shared/Working/infa01/WorkflowLogs/wf_MASTER_DAILY.log]"
w="Workflow run status" s="Start time" e="End time"
{ 
    printf "%s\n" "$w" "$s" "$e"
    grep -oP "$w: \\[\\K.*?(?=\\])" <<<"$string" 
    date -d "$(grep -oP "$s: \\[\\K.*?(?=\\])" <<<"$string")" "+%F %T"
    date -d "$(grep -oP "$e: \\[\\K.*?(?=\\])" <<<"$string")" "+%F %T"
} | paste -d'|' - - -
```

outputs

```
Workflow run status|Start time|End time
Succeeded|2016-06-04 13:14:11|2016-06-04 13:20:37
```

Comment: I think I will go with your code ,works fine as well. @glenn jackman

Answer (score 2):

If you can get the "start time" value using your `grep` expression, you can use below `date` command to convert it into desired timestamp if you have `-d` option, like :

```
date -d 'Sat Jun 04 13:14:11 2016' +'%Y-%m-%d %T'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final working code to grep & format the date

```
grep "Start time:" | cut -d'[' -f2 | cut -d']' -f1 | read dt ; date -d "$dt" +'%Y-%m-%d %T'
```